# Thread 1 : 1.1 breakpoint on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

i try to create my first application on Xcode ,first I tried only to overwrite the text of a label at same moment when it is write in a TextField.
Now I try just for fun , to set hidden a second label (Label2) from Utility area and with the button ok to keep these unhide but the I'll give error (Thread 1 :breakpoint 1.1).
After I try solve the problem, I think to save the text in a var String and when I press the "ok" button , it set the Label2.text=String.
Anyway ,When I build and run this code it give the same ERROR .
Anyone can help me ?
thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!;
    @IBOutlet weak var labelRes: UILabel!;
    @IBOutlet weak var textReceveirer: UITextField!;

    var myString : String = " "

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myString=textReceveirer.text!
        labelRes.text = "hello \(myString)"
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe the error reason is not show in the post, can you provide more code you think may cause your problem?

Comment: i do some changes to the code , now the error is breakpoint 1.4 on the line of the declaration of myString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!;
    @IBOutlet weak var textReciver: UITextField!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelOne.text = " "
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        labelOne.text = textReciver.text
    }

}
```

Comment: I see no explanation

Answer (score 0):

write in your code `var String=""`that replace with

```
var Variable : String = ""
```

or check that connection inspector..

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is at line

```
var String=""
```

**String** is data type ,

if you want to create variable type of string you may use follow this

```
var myVariable : String = ""
```